# Kotlin - toSet() versus distinct()

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin, I could obtain the distinct elements of an `Iterable<T>` using the following two methods...

**Calling `.toSet()`**

```kotlin
val items = listOf(1, 2, 2, 3)
val distinctItems: Set<Int> = items.toSet()
```

**Calling `.distinct()`**

```kotlin
val items = listOf(1, 2, 2, 3)
val distinctItems: List<Int> = items.distinct()
```

Aside from the fact that the return type is different (`Set<Int>` versus `List<Int>`) is there any advantage (i.e. performance) of calling one over the other?

**Note:** It seems that Kotlin favours the use of `List<T>` over `Set<T>` for most operations, and I guess that makes sense where lists of items are *probably* more common than sets of items. I tend to use `Set<T>` more often than not, especially where set semantics make more sense than list semantics.

Comment: `toSet()` is more performant. `toList()` internally copies the items to a set and then copies the resulting set’s items to a list.

Comment: `return this.toMutableSet().toList()` https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/common/src/generated/_Collections.kt

Comment: also, `toSet()` returns a `LinkedHashSet` which is worse in performance compared to a `HashSet` for some operations, so you may want to consider using `.toHashSet()` instead, if performance is critical (and you can always force the type to `val distinctItems: Set<Int> = items.toHashSet()` if you want to keep using the immutable interface)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Iterable.distinct()` uses a `Set` internally. So basically you can expect O(#distinctElements) of performance impact.

For example https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/acd29481bd9ca68739c73140f0bdbd9b9cdb22b4/libraries/stdlib/common/src/generated/_Collections.kt#L1609

```
public fun <T> Iterable<T>.distinct(): List<T> {
    return this.toMutableSet().toList()
}
```